# How can I fix my developer's console?

Tags: google-chrome

I use google chrome and I used to have a console at the bottom of the page where I could edit the CSS of the loaded page. Now that has disappeared and instead I have to the right another panel, now I want to old one back where I could make liv changes to the CSS. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the keyboard:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the drawer (the sub-menu with this console view.)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to toggle the dock (main menu) between side and bottom display (<kbd>Meta keys</kbd> vary on OsX)

Or enlarge the docker window by pulling left until you can see these in the top right:

[image: chrome debugger drawer toggle, settings, dock toggle]

(the left icon is the drawer you want to hide, the right icon is the dock you want moved, the middle is the settings which includes the keyboard shortcut info.)